# set perl regular expression search start at a given position in a long string

Tags: regex, performance, perl, tokenize

I want to extract tokens for a simple backtracking parser from a potentially long input code text. My setup is to use an integer cursor which holds the next-to-read position within the text, initially 0. Then I want to use `substr` to extract simple short tokens and perlre for more complicated tokens. So the cursor position between subsequent regex searches might jump forward (after a successful token substring match) or backward (when backtracking).

My question is: How can I efficiently constrain the starting position for a perlregex search so that it searches for a matching token only from that position.

For example, I want to get the decimal number tokens in an exemplary text

```
my $text = 'long text with 2 numbers 3928 in it';
```

and current cursor position is 25. My current wisdom for this problem is either generating a (probably inefficiently long) substring

```
my $tail = substr $text, 25;
printf "%s\n",
    $tail =~ /^\d+/
    ? "match: $&"
    : "miss";
```

or manipulating the `\G` modifier by a (probably inefficient) extra pattern match (note here that `25` would have to be a variable in the real tokenizer)

```
$text =~ /.{25}/gcm;
printf "%s\n",
    $text =~ /\G\d+/
    ? "match: $&"
    : "miss";
```

The latter alternative bears the additional cosmetic weakness that it is probably not thread safe. This is no issue in what I am doing right now, but I also highlight this concern within my question for those who might use multi-threading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pos](http://p3rl.org/pos) is an lvalue and can be assigned to.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{ say };

my $text = 'long text with 2 numbers 3928 in it';

pos($text) = 25;

say for $text =~ /(\d+)/g;
```